# How do I use slashes with query parameters?

Tags: .htaccess, slash

I know it's very possible to have www.website.com/stuff/2 instead of www.website.com/stuff/page?=2 for page 2 of "stuff". How would I go about doing that though? I do not know what to search for.

Edit to say that I am using PHP and $_GET to get the parameters. This is so widely used so I didn't think it would be very difficult.

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 common ways:

1. [Rewrite](https://www.google.com/search?q=url+rewrite) the URL internally from `.../2` to `.../?page=2`.
2. Use the ["path info"](https://www.google.com/search?q=pathinfo) mechanism of your web language. A script at `/stuff/index.xyz` would have a path info of `2` with the given URL.
3. Have the web program capture all URLs and use [routing](https://www.google.com/search?q=url+routing) to determine which function to call and what values to pass it.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what you're using.

PHP ? I believe you're looking for apache .htaccess [URL Rewriting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is very much possible with a simple mod_rewrite rule in your .htaccess. Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(stuff)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1.php?page=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```